# Ubuntu iptables logs not going to any log file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to put logs in iptables but I can not find any log in any file. Although when I  run dmesg command, I can see the iptables entries. But the same entry doesn't go to any log file. Here is my iptables rule :

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp  -j LOG --log-level info --log-prefix " [ IPTABLES " --log-uid
```

Here is the syslog.conf file :

```
#  /etc/syslog.conf Configuration file for syslogd.
#
#           For more information see syslog.conf(5)
#           manpage.

#
# First some standard logfiles.  Log by facility.
#

auth,authpriv.*      -/var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*          -/var/log/cron.log
daemon.*            -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*              -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*               -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*              -/var/log/mail.log
user.*              -/var/log/user.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
mail.info           -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn           -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err         -/var/log/mail.err

# Logging for INN news system
#
news.crit        -/var/log/news/news.crit
news.err         -/var/log/news/news.err
news.notice         -/var/log/news/news.notice

#
# Some `catch-all' logfiles.
#
*.=debug;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    news.none;mail.none -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    cron,daemon.none;\
    mail,news.none      -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg             *

#
# I like to have messages displayed on the console, but only on a virtual
# console I usually leave idle.
#
#daemon,mail.*;\
#   news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
#   *.=debug;*.=info;\
#   *.=notice;*.=warn   /dev/tty8

# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the `xconsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke `xconsole' with the `-file' option:
#
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
#
# NOTE: adjust the list below, or you'll go crazy if you have a reasonably
#      busy site..
#
daemon.*;mail.*;\
    news.err;\
    *.=debug;*.=info;\
    *.=notice;*.=warn   -/var/log/xconsole.log
```

Here are some more details :

```
root@us4839:~# ps ax | grep syslog
11336 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep syslog
17910 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/syslogd
root@us4839:~#
root@us4839:~#
root@us4839:~# lsof /var/log/syslog
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE     NODE NAME
syslogd 17910 root    2w   REG   0,42 5508 57114744 /var/log/syslog
root@us4839:~#
```

Am I doing anything wrong in this rule or there is something wrong somewhere else ?

Comment: Is your syslog configured to write that log to any place?

Comment: Right now, NO. Though I will do it once I start seeing the logs in any of the log files.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, this is OpenVZ VPS. I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: Um. How would you expect to see any logs in any of the log files if syslog isn't configured to write the log?

Comment: should it not go to its default location ? Like /var/log/kern.log or /var/log/syslog. I have another server and it works there. Once its there in the default log files then I put a rule to filter them to another file. I guess filters are needed to separate logs in different file for better house keeping.

Comment: Add your syslog config to your question, specifically the part containing the facility `kern`.

Comment: Please add it *in the question*, not in a comment.

Comment: Check your `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/kern.log`

Comment: Can you post the entirety of your iptables? Please modify your question with the output of `iptables-save`

Comment: @TimLamballais -  There is nothing relating to iptables in those files.

Comment: @pepoluan -  I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @AbhayPS uhh, just remembered that you said you saw the log inside `dmesg` output... no need for `iptables-save`, but doesn't hurt. What does `ps ax | grep syslog` return? Also, what does `lsof /var/log/syslog` return?

Comment: @pepoluan - just edited the question again.

Comment: Hmm... I see you're using `syslogd` instead of `rsyslogd` ... perhaps the configuration is for rsyslog instead of syslog-ng? I have to give up at this point...

Comment: @pepoluan - Thanks, I know you tried your best. Anyways, I don't see any problem with the config. I think I need to change provider and get another server.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem a long time ago and it is (in part) related to the OpenVZ architecture.

Can you please confirm that:

- the iptables rule syntax is correct
- syslog & klogd are running (as far as I can remember klogd is required for openVZ to log kernel messages properly)

<strike>Does *dmesg* output contain the iptables log lines?</strike> If yes, then this is likely a syslog config issue. You could try to add a directive that's placing kernel.warn in a separate iptables.log file.

**Edit**
Did you check the logfiles manually? If yes I'd grep for it e.g. with

```
grep -rl "MAC" /var/log/*   # should match, else use the interface name or IPTABLES as pattern
```

just to make sure...

Comment: klogd was required on those old systems to log _any_ kernel messages whether OpenVZ or not.

Comment: Hi, justlovingIT, the iptables rules were right and worked well on other servers. This problem was only on VPS provided by a specific vendor. I tried the same rules on another VPS provied by another vendor and everything was working as expected. May be its the problem of virtualization architecture with that specific vendor. Anyways, I changed the provider.

Comment: I'm also having no logging showing up. Its a vps, but I don't know if its OpenVZ or not.